# Questions regarding algorithm used by matchTemplate() in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, fft, cross-correlation

At the [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be) there is the documentation on how opencv matches images with `cv::matchTemplate`. I am interested in equation 5.

In [literature](https://isas.iar.kit.edu/pdf/SPIE01_BriechleHanebeck_CrossCorr.pdf) I have found that this equation is usually computed via a truncated Fourier transform or with other truncated expansion on a basis set to better the performances. Obviously, this is an approximation.

I have implemented the same formula reported in the link without any discrepancies. The results are slightly different. I would like to know how opencv implements this metrics.

I have read the source code, but they use a foggy calls to kernel functions. Do they uses Fourier transform or other basis sets like rectangular basis functions?

Comment: Maybe they use FFT.

Comment: How much is "sligtly different" ? Might just be floating point precision shenanigans.

Comment: The differences between the two implemented metrics is about the first decimal digit. I was wondering if an approximation has been made.

Comment: due to the `mask` argument, `matchTemplate` can't use fourier transforms. it has to compute everything element by element.

Comment: Can you link to the source code ?

Comment: I do not use a mask. Also in this case OpenCV does the exact calculation?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share my source code by company policy.

Comment: No, the source code of OpenCV !

Comment: Here you can find the code for the matchTemplate function https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp. The line where the specific metrics is implemented is 437.